# PivotChart in SAS

Tags: charts, sas, pivot

Is there any possibility to create a pivot chart in SAS? Assume I have the following data:

```
Date    Volume
1/1     6
1/2     8
1/3     5
1/1     2
1/2     4
```

The output should have three bars, one for 1/1, 1/2 and 1/3 with volumes of 8, 12, and 5, respectively (adding up the volumes based on dates).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I would break this down into two parts:

part one:

```
proc sql;
    create table volume_data as
    select date, sum(volume) as volume
    from old_data
    group by date
    order by date;
quit;
```

Now that you have your data in proper form go to part two:

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the jargon you are using means, but if you want to plot the sum of VOLUME for each DATE value it is very simple.

```
data have ;
  length date volume 8;
  informat date date9.;
  format date date9. ;
  input date volume;
cards;
01JAN2015 6
02JAN2015 8
03JAN2015 5
01JAN2015 2
02JAN2015 4
;;;;
proc sgplot;
  hbar date / response=volume stat=sum;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is no.  SAS does not have pivot table functionality. It is possible to code the data to summarize it any way you want to. It is also possible, though I don't use this functionality, to have SAS create Excel Pivot Table XML coding.  See [White Paper Here](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2007/055-2007.pdf)

I use SAS to create flat file datasets (sometimes 100's of mbytes) to export into excel, and then use Excel to summarize it with its very nice Pivot functionality.  In addition, it is easy to update the source data tab directly from SAS as needed.

See [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7aANSYtlIBKWEJpNzRvc1hqWTA/view?usp=sharing) for extremely pared down example.

Best,
john